# D3.js Fisheye.js strange mousemove behavior

Tags: javascript, select, d3.js, fisheye

I'm trying to use a [Fisheye.js](https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/fisheye) effect in a large Tilfold-Reingold diagram (~4000 objects). The effect I'm aiming for is something like [this example](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/).

I must be using the Fisheye.js incorrectly as my example doesn't seem to be effecting the desired node or the text (at all).

https://jsfiddle.net/Nyquist212/7b7q9ra9/

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
svg.on("mousemove", function() {

fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

node.each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })

node.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x - d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y - d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 10; });

node.select("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x - d.x; })
    .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y - d.y; });

});
```

UPDATED: The intention is to target each node and associated description text, to make them more readable.

Comment: in your code you are doing fisheye to all nodes when `mouse-moves`. So what do you want on single node or all when mouse moves.??? also just node radius gets 10 from 2. please give some more info.

Comment: @Hashy I'm trying to apply fisheye distortion to each node and corresponding text label to make the more readable.

Comment: See this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840226/transformation-issues-when-implementing-fisheye-distortion-in-a-radial-tree).  Gotta make the fisheye play nice with a radial layout...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Mark - Thank you for the link to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20840226/transformation-issues-when-implementing-fisheye-distortion-in-a-radial-tree)

@Peter- Thank you for the text label part.

I managed to get it working combining the two.

http://fiddle.jshell.net/Nyquist212/w05nkyry/3/

Comment: It is really cool now. Do not forget to accept this answer, to help others to find easier the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

I played around with your fiddle. I noticed, that the svg variable is not what its name suggest. And I also managed to increase the size of the texts. It still a little weird, but I think it is closer to your goal.

```
d3.select("svg").on("mousemove", function() { //here

fisheye.focus(d3.mouse(this));

node.each(function(d) { d.fisheye = fisheye(d); })

node.selectAll("circle")
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x - d.x; })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y - d.y; })
    .attr("r", function(d) { return d.fisheye.z * 10; });

node.select("text")
    .attr("dx", function(d) { return d.fisheye.x - d.x; })
    .attr("dy", function(d) { return d.fisheye.y - d.y; })
    .attr("style", function(d){return "font-size :"+d.fisheye.z*10+"px";}); //here

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/7b7q9ra9/23/